# What's the importance of the twins in the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, paterson

In [***Paterson***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5247022/) (2016), Paterson sees and pays attention to twins in the city.

What's the reason for this emphasis on twins in the movie?

In the beginning,  Paterson's wife says that he dreamed about having two babies. Is it all because of this dream that they can not make it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The twins symbolize the duality of existence.

> In Paterson, Jim Jarmusch’s newest film, the viewer explores life’s inherently dualistic nature through conflicts that arise from a disconnect between our expectations and reality. Paterson makes the argument that identity, creativity and existence are two sides of the same coin and that because of, not despite, this dualism, beauty is able to exist. Through poems that capture small moments such as the details of a matchbox or rain falling from the sky, Jarmusch shows us the world that exists within the one we create for ourselves and how to reach that world in today’s technologically-connected, fast-paced society.

Source: http://culturevulturesla.com/paterson-jim-jarmusch/

Comment: You're right. I didn't consider this dualism. But at the end of movie i think Paterson decided to accept the reality of his life.

Comment: @klaymen I think most of us do. But still this second self (the one who dreams, the one that is a poet) exists in all of us.

Comment: At least i'm sure about myself. It exists.

Comment: @klaymen If you think that my answer is the correct one, don't forget to select it as the one that answers your question!

Comment: Your answer was a good one but i'm not completly convinced with it. I have be waiting for more answers. howerver it seems there no more answers.

Comment: @klaymen Sure, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the meaning of the twins is to make the deep connection of twins commonplace. As if we all can experience this connection if we just allow ourselves to be present in the moment with the people with whom we come across daily and with those who come into our lives in any given moment.